# Floated divs expand on hover, moves second row div to left rather than moving it down

Tags: html, css

So it was hard to get my question in to a single line. Basically, I have a bunch of generated boxes from a php script and they need to be the same height. There is a short description within each box which is half hidden, when you hover the box expands to reveal the rest of the content.

My question is, is it possible to make the full row underneath move down the expanded amount without the div jumping to the left. If you hover over div 1, you'll see div 4 jump to the left and cause a knock on effect which is unappealing, however if you hover over div 3 you'll notice the full second row moves down in a unified fashion. I'm not sure enitrely why this happens for one and not the other. Please see attached fiddle

```
<div class="hover"></div>

.expand{height:100px; width:120px; text-align:center; 
float:left; vertical-align:middle; border:1px solid black; margin:10px;}

.expand:hover {height:120px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n90ua1cp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
.expand{
     height:100px;
     width:120px;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:top;
     border:1px solid black;
     margin:10px;
     display: inline-block;
}

.expand:hover {
     height:120px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n90ua1cp/1/)**

Comment: Yes actually, this is the effect I want however I already have display:inline-block added to my box in the application and it doesnt work like this! :/ How confusing..

Comment: beware...copy all my code...i have change not only in the display

Comment: Also, you can use negative borders on hover to help stabilize things. example, replace the expand:hover with .expand:hover {height:120px; margin: 10px 10px -10px 10px;}

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper div to proper output.

```
In html
<div class="row">
<div class="expand">1</div>
<div class="expand">2</div>
<div class="expand">3</div>
</div>

 In css
.row{height: 150px;}
```

For demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandipkaranjekar/n90ua1cp/8/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not applicable to this situation as the content is dynamically generated. Otherwise it would be good. The selected answer works perfect in my situation.